# What is the proper way to manage windows in pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, python-3.6, qt-designer

In the application I am building I have a few "windows" I am working with. I am trying to figure out, according to python/industry standards, how to properly manage them. I have a warning screen, disclaimer screen, main gui, and essentially a message box for communicating errors.

What my customer would like to transpire is the program displaying the warning screen (QDialog), and then the disclaimer screen (QDialog) on button click, then the main gui (QMainWindow) after the user has agreed to the disclaimer. The message box is only used when the user needs to be alerted to some event. **Note: I am using qt desinger**

I'm trying to approach this project in a very object orient manner, but I'm struggling to implement this in such a way that it isn't a complete mess. What I intended to do was have a main class that initializes all the pieces of the application at startup, with two controllers (one for the gui and one for the backend processes).

So far my gui controller is failing miserably. Initially, I created a class for each of the windows, and then tried creating objects for each in the gui controller. I was forced to move all the classes into a single file, remove the gui controller class code, and utilize this file as the "main" for the application to even get the first window to launch. I am still unable to switch between windows, at best I can close the one that is currently open. **What is the proper way to structure an application like this in Python3/PyQt5?**

Some code:

```
#There used to be another class for gui_controller that instantiated all the below (pyqt5 doesn't work this way as I've come to learn)

#Used to be in its own file.
class WarningScreen(QDialog, Ui_SomeWarningScreen):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(WarningScreen, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.accept_button_2.clicked.connect(self.acknowledge_warning)

    def acknowledge_warning(self):
        window = Disclaimer()
        window.show()
        self.close()

#Used to be in its own file.
class DisclaimerScreen(QDialog, Ui_UsageDislaimer):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DisclaimerScreen, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

#This was initially in the main class for the application.
if __name__ == "__main__":

    APP = QApplication(sys.argv)

    WINDOW = WarningScreen()

    WINDOW.show()

    sys.exit(APP.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The open window is not shown by a simple fact, the local variables are deleted when its scope is finished, in your case `window = Disclaimer()` is a local variable that will be deleted so a possible solution is:

```
def acknowledge_warning(self):
    self.window = Disclaimer()
    self.window.show()
    self.close()
```

Although a better option is to create a class or function where the logic of the interaction between windows is implemented, in the following part I show an example:

```
class WarningScreen(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_SomeWarningScreen):
    closed = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(WarningScreen, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.accept_button_2.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.accept_button_2.clicked.connect(self.closed)


class DisclaimerScreen(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_UsageDislaimer):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DisclaimerScreen, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


class Controller:
    def __init__(self):
        self.warning = WarningScreen()
        self.disclaimer = DisclaimerScreen()

        self.warning.closed.connect(self.disclaimer.show)
        self.warning.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    APP = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Controller()
    sys.exit(APP.exec_())
```

Comment: I hadn't even considered the variable scope. That actually makes a lot of sense now. (This is the second time you've helped me eyllanesc :) ). Just curious though, for the sake of clarity in the rest of the application, would it be possible to move the code at the bottom into the actual "main class", without disturbing anything? Could you also explain the use of parent=None if possible?

Comment: @BobFromBilling explain yourself better, which part you do not see clearly, you do not like the following: `self.warning.accept_button_2.clicked.connect(self.disclaimer.show)` .On the other hand if my answers helped you do not forget to mark it as correct, if You do not know how to do it, review the [tour], that's the best way to thank.

Comment: No I was referring to the if __name__ == "__main__": section. Does that need to remain in the same file, or can I move it to another one? The use of that code block is a bit foreign to me, I understand the concept, but I'm coming from Java with the literal main class.

Comment: `parent=None`:  In Qt there is a relation of dependencies, for example an object that belongs to Qt have a life cycle different from that of normal python objects, so Qt has many times the responsibility of eliminating the memory of their children, so relationship allows Qt easily, remember that PyQt has a strong C ++ component, so it complies with the C ++ rules, for example a direct memory management through the destructors thing that is python often manages it and does not give it the possibility to the developer.

Comment: @BobFromBilling in java there is a main class that must necessarily have the method public static void main (...), called main function, that is equivalent to `if __name__ ==" __main __ ":`, in the case of python you can have those functions in all the .py and many times it is used to test a component, but only the `if __name__ ==" __main __ ":` of the file that is launched, the others will be ignored. Python is not Java, python does not comply with java rules, I think you want to have a main.py file where only that function exists: am I right?

Comment: @BobFromBilling You can move the content of `if __name__ == "__main__":` to another file.

Comment: Yes I would like to move that statement into a main.py file where the entire program will be launched from. I am going to try implementing now. Thank you for all the answers, it is very helpful. Could you explain the usage of: closed = QtCore.pyqtSignal() self.accept_button_2.clicked.connect(self.close) self.accept_button_2.clicked.connect(self.closed), what exactly is taking place here. This will be my last question, thank you.

Comment: @BobFromBilling read http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html, there you understand that it is a signal and that it is a slot in the world of Qt. Assuming you know conceptually that it is a signal and slot, with `closed = QtCore.pyqtSignal()` a new signal is being created, in my logic that signal must be thrown when the button is pressed, so I connect the clicked signal to that new signal, that is, a signal can send another signal. instead,

Comment: @BobFromBilling [cont.] `self.accept_button_2.clicked.connect (self.close)` is connecting the clicked signal to the close slot, that is, each time the button is pressed the clicked signal will be emitted and this signal will invoke the close method.

Comment: I should really word my questions better, I imagine it seems like I don't understand any of this. So I assume that pyqt objects have a built in function .close() that is connected to a slot, am I correct? So my understanding is that when the button is pressed, the close slot is signaled to call the close() function, as well as signaling disclaimer.show() through the connection to the closed signal. Is this also correct?

Comment: @BobFromBilling the windows that inherit from QWidget have the close () method that closes the window, in the code I signal that I want to close the window when the button is pressed, so I connect the clicked signal to the close slot. Take the time and read tutorials on the concept of signals and slots, that is fundamental in the world of Qt, is the basic piece.